# Interface Modport Connection to Testbench Environment in SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a simple arbiter design that grants one of the two requests with priority to the first one. I want to connect it to the test bench designed in SystemVerilog. I want to connect my environment to my DUT through an interface on two positions: 1) To a monitor that monitors the bus 2). To a driver, to drive relevant test cases.

For the two connections, I have defined two `modports`. I have instantiated my DUT and interface in a top module and have tried to pass the reference to these two `modports` using virtual interfaces. However, I'm getting a compile time error as below:

> ** Error: Environment.sv(8): Illegal assignment to type 'virtual interface arbi_if' from type 'virtual interface arb_if': Virtual interface type 'arbi_if' cannot be assigned type 'arb_if'.

Different codes are as below:

arb_if.sv

```
interface   arb_if(
    input   clk
);

logic   [1:0]   request;
logic   [1:0]   grant;
logic           rst;

clocking cb @(posedge clk);
    input   grant;
    output  request;
endclocking

modport TEST(clocking cb, output rst);    
modport ARBI(input clk, grant, output rst, request);    
modport MONT(input clk, grant, rst, request);

endinterface
```

Environment.sv

```
class Environment;
    virtual arbi_if af;

    virtual arbi_if.TEST aft;
    virtual arbi_if.TEST afm;

    function new(virtual arb_if af);
        this.af = af;
        this.aft = af.TEST;
        this.afm = af.MONT;
    endfunction

endclass
```

test.sv

```
`include "Environment.sv"

class test;
    Environment env;
    virtual arb_if af;

    function new(virtual arb_if afi);
        this.af = afi; // Compiler complains for this line.
    endfunction

    ...
endclass
```

tb_top.sv

```
module tb_top;

reg clk;

initial
begin
    clk = 0;
    forever #5 clk = ~clk;
end

arb_if arbif(clk);
arb a(arbif);
test ta(arbif);

endmodule
```

In summary, I want to know how reference to modports are passed to different classes from a top module? 
The above code has been trimmed to make a minimum working example.

Comment: you name your interface `arb_if`, but in the Evironment.sv it is `arbi_if`.

Comment: also, the standard is a bit vague here. It is unclear if `this.aft = af.TEST;` could be used, however, `this.aft = af;` is ok.

Comment: @Serge Thanks for pointing out the mistake. In fact, it was the error. However, I still wonder how will both the monitor and driver will connect to the same DUT when the two interfaces are different: one we are giving as arb_if.TEST and the other as arb_if.MONT. At least how will the compiler/simulator know that I'm connecting the DUT on the same pins but to two different components.

Comment: it is still the same interface, modports are just different views of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modports are just restricted access rights when declaring interface ports or virtual interface variables, or making assignments to them. This is explained in section *25.9 Virtual interfaces* and *25.10 Access to interface objects* of the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM.

Essentially you can always make interface type assignments from an *unrestricted* interface instance to a `modport` *restricted* port or variable, but you can never make the assignment in the reverse direction (restricted to unrestricted), or from one modport type to another modport type.

Comment: it is not clear about restricted to restricted assignment between the same modport types, as in OPs example (TEST to TEST). vcs errors out in this case. nc and mentor do not.

Comment: Having different behaviors across tools certainly makes it unclear for the users of those tools. The *LRM* is clear in the sections I mentioned that a `modport` is part of the data type, and section *6.22.3 Assignment compatible* say matching types are assignment compatible. Section 25.9 also makes an exception that allows unrestricted to restricted types to be assignments compatible.